# Can Mac OSX 10.5 (Leopard) run 64-bit processes?

Tags: macos, 32bit-64bit

I am curious if it is possible to run FFmpeg (or another command-line process) that is compiled with 10.6 (Snow Leopard) on 10.5 (Leopard).

From what I understand, 10.6 compiles into 64-bit executables. However, I'm not sure how this works on 10.5 as I do not have a machine available to test. I am currently using one of the static builds from http://ffmpeg.arrozcru.org/autobuilds/ffmpeg/macosx64/static/

Ideas? Anyone willing to test? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can run 64 bit processes in 10.5. You should build your code with the 10.5 SDK though (it will still run on 10.6 of course).

You can even run 64 bit processes on 10.4 so long as they don't use Cocoa or any frameworks which are not 64-bit (effectively this just means command line tools etc).